# Wordpress post filter

Tags: posts

Filtering my custom post type by published year.
I have something like this:

> Filter posts for 2015 / 2016.

The years are links which redirecting with $_GET vars like `'?year=2015'` and `'?year=2016'`

In the custom page i have this:

```
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : '';

if ($year == '2015') {
    $the_query = new WP_Query('year=2015&post_type=events');
} else {
    $the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=events');
}
```

But if i click the 2015 year i'm redirecting to 404 page. I tried make query like this `$the_query = new WP_Query('year=2015&post_type=events');` and it works, but cannot make it work with the GET or is there a better way to do that? (sorry for my English)

Also tried this:

```
$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : '';

$the_query = new WP_Query('year='. (int)$year .'&post_type=events');
```

And here is problem that my 2016 posts are filtering but if i pass 2015 to GET parametr im redirecting to 404 page.

Comment: Are you sure you have any posts in 2015?

Comment: @Robbert Of course, i have posts in 2014, 2015, 2016.

Comment: Have you refreshed your permalinks already?

Comment: @Robbert What do you mean by that?

Comment: In your admin dashboard under settings -> permalinks you can save your permalink structure. While doing this, your permalinks will be reflushed. Sometimes this will help with 404 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to hook into the [pre_get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) function to change the query by adding this code to your functions.php file:

```
<?php
function filter_by_date( $query ) {

   if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

      if ( isset( $_GET['year'] ) ) {
         $query->set( 'year', $_GET['year'] );
         $query->set( 'post_type', 'events' );
      }
   }

   return $query;

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_date' );
?>
```